# Get all properties of an HTML element without running JS inside browser

Tags: javascript

I need to find all available properties of any HTML element.

Using javascript if we have to find all properties of an html element we do this

```
function getAllProps(objects){
    props = []
    for(var key in objects) {
        props.push(key)
    }
    return props;
}
```

And we use above function in this way:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
console.log(getAllProps(btn));
```

Above code is completely browser dependent. We need to run this code inside browser to get it running.

I want to know, is it possible to do the same using cscript.exe or any other external JS interpreter?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: So your question is basically "is there any JavaScript implementation which is not tied to a browser", to which the answer is "yes".

Comment: yes exactly!and how can i achieve the above described thing ?

Comment: you can do it in nearly every high level programming language, pick one and start googling man, if you have a specific programming related question we will be glad to help, but your question is way too general

Comment: I tried to run the same thing using cscript.exe but i'm getting one error like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document' is undefined" which is very obvious. coz i don't have any browser,

Comment: c# and HtmlAguilityPack and you can write your own interpreter in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can not do this. To get the properties of an object you need that object and the get that object you need an implementation of that object. The best thing you can do is to look into the DOM specification and read what properties should be present in a conforming implementation.

There are implementation of the DOM for JavaScript runtimes that are not browser runtimes but then you are still depending on a specific implementation. [Here is one for Node.js](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) but I have no idea how good or complete it is.